# Contingency tables from data.frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, aggregate

I'm trying to create 4-way contingency table from my data set. 
My data set looks like this:

```
a <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
b <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
group1 <- sample(letters[25:26], 12, replace = T)
group2 <- sample(letters[7:10], 12, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(a, b, group1, group2)
```

I tried with `aggregate` function. Everything is OK when creating 3-way contingency table

```
aggregate(cbind(a, b) ~ group1, data = df, FUN = table)
  group1 a.0 a.1 b.0 b.1
1      y   3   4   3   4
2      z   2   3   2   3
```

However, when adding second grouping variable, the output is confusing and not desired.

```
aggregate(. ~ group1 + group2, data = df, FUN = table)
  group1 group2    a    b
1      y      g    3    3
2      z      g    1    1
3      z      h    1    1
4      y      i    1    1
5      z      i    1    1
6      y      j 2, 1    3
7      z      j 1, 1 1, 1
```

As my original data set is quite large, I would appreciate some nice elegant and automatic approach to deal with it. T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear about the expected output.  Perhaps we need `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = c("group1", "group2")), 
                       group1 + group2 ~variable + value, length)
```

Or use the `recast` (wrapper for `melt/dcast` from `reshape2`)

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, measure.var = c("a", "b"), ... ~ variable + value, length)
#    group1 group2 a_0 a_1 b_0 b_1
#1      y      g   1   4   3   2
#2      y      h   1   0   1   0
#3      y      j   1   1   0   2
#4      z      g   2   0   0   2
#5      z      i   0   1   0   1
#6      z      j   0   1   1   0
```

The OP's `aggregate` give this output

```
aggregate(. ~ group1 + group2, data = df, FUN = table)
#  group1 group2    a    b
#1      y      g 1, 4 3, 2
#2      z      g    2    2
#3      y      h    1    1
#4      z      i    1    1
#5      y      j 1, 1    2
#6      z      j    1    1
```

If we want `aggregate` to get both the `levels`, then convert to a `factor` with `levels` specified and do the `table`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(cbind(a, b) ~ group1 + group2, data = df, 
              FUN = function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 0:1))))
#  group1 group2 a.0 a.1 b.0 b.1
#1      y      g   1   4   3   2
#2      z      g   2   0   0   2
#3      y      h   1   0   1   0
#4      z      i   0   1   0   1
#5      y      j   1   1   0   2
#6      z      j   0   1   1   0
```

If we want all the combinations, there is `drop = FALSE` in `dcast`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = c("group1", "group2")), group1 + group2 ~
                   variable + value, length, drop = FALSE)
```

Or in `recast`

```
recast(df, measure.var = c("a", "b"), ... ~ variable + value, length, drop = FALSE)
```

NOTE: There was no `set.seed` for `sample`, so the output showed here will be different from the OP's output

Comment: Great, thank you for quick reply! Now I see that `aggregate` only does not print zeros which confused me. Although `melt/dcast` and `recast` work nicely, is there any way how to make `aggregate` to give also zeros?

Comment: @Adela  Updated the post.

Comment: Great, well the last question. I noticed that there are no values for `z-h` and `y-i` groups combination in `do.call` output (no surprise). Is it possible to print zero values for them as well? Or do I have to put them here manually?

Comment: @Adela Updated the post.  I think in `aggregate`, we get the combinations that have the values.  I you need, then you may have to `merge` with the full combination dataset.  But, in `dcast/recast`, there is `drop = FALSE` i.e. `merge(expand.grid(group1 = unique(df$group1), group2 = unique(df$group2)),  do.call(data.frame, aggregate(cbind(a, b) ~ group1 + group2, data = df, 
  FUN = function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 0:1))))
 , all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Great, this was really useful. Thank you for your ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit complicated, but maybe it helps, as I understood you just wanted to count so this could help:

```
#Creating data
a <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
b <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
group1 <- sample(letters[25:26], 12, replace = T)
group2 <- sample(letters[7:10], 12, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(a, b, group1, group2)

# Counting variable a and b seperatly in a data frame
counta <- xtabs( ~ group1 + group2 + a, data = df)
countb <- xtabs( ~ group1 + group2 + b, data = df)
df.a <- data.frame(counta)
df.b <- data.frame(countb)

#Now merging the data.frames:
result.df <- merge(df.a, df.b, by.x= c("group1", "group2"),by.y=c("group1", "group2"), all = TRUE)

# Result Looks like this:
result.df

#          group1 group2 a Freq.x    b Freq.y
#   1       y      g     0      2    0      1
#   2       y      g     0      2    1      1
#   3       y      g     1      0    0      1
#   4       y      g     1      0    1      1
#   5       y      h     0      1    0      0
#   6       y      h     0      1    1      1
#   7       y      h     1      0    0      0
#   8       y      h     1      0    1      1
#   9       y      i     0      1    0      2
#  10       y      i     0      1    1      1
#  11       y      i     1      2    0      2
#  12       y      i     1      2    1      1
#  13       y      j     0      0    0      0
#  14       y      j     0      0    1      0
#  15       y      j     1      0    0      0
#  16       y      j     1      0    1      0
#  17       z      g     0      0    0      1
#  18       z      g     0      0    1      0
#  19       z      g     1      1    0      1
#  20       z      g     1      1    1      0
#  21       z      h     0      0    0      1
#  22       z      h     0      0    1      1
#  23       z      h     1      2    0      1
#  24       z      h     1      2    1      1
#  25       z      i     0      1    0      0
#  26       z      i     0      1    1      1
#  27       z      i     1      0    0      0
#  28       z      i     1      0    1      1
#  29       z      j     0      0    0      0
#  30       z      j     0      0    1      2
#  31       z      j     1      2    0      0
#  32       z      j     1      2    1      2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is nice. However, as I said, my original dataset is quite large and has a lot of columns, hence it would be too complicated. Anyway, for my short example it works pretty well :)